# How can I convert AVI files to FLV files with the highest quality?

Tags: conversion, flash, avi, flv

I want to convert some of the AVI files I recorded (presentations) to FLV so I can host them on a website and offer them to my visitors. I have done this sort of thing before but the quality they came out as would not be good enough for what I plan on doing here.

Does anyone have a link to a guide or any experience they can offer in converting AVI to FLV with minimal quality loss? A lot of my presentations are 720p as well, so I'd want to keep the aspect ratio the same as the source video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest [`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/). If you are on windows, I suggest the [most recent autobuild](http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/autobuilds/).

```
ffmpeg -i foo.avi -ar 22050 -qscale 1 bar.flv
```

`ffmpeg` is very tweakable, so you might try searching for `flv` specific encoding options. Also see the [ffmpeg docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html)

Comment: Thank you :) That command actually made bar.flv about 300mb bigger than the source .avi file, so looks like I have some tweaking to do, but this gives me a strong base. Thanks again.

Comment: @Josh, you could try it without `-qscale` just to see how it comes out. In theory `-sameq` uses the same quality as the source. You might also try `-qmin 1`, `-qmax 15` or something similar.

Finally, you may wish to use two pass video encoding. see: `-pass` at http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC10